# Названия вкладок TabLayout отображаются не полностью

Tags: android

У меня в активити есть TabLayout с 8-ю вкладками, но названия этих вкладок сужаются так что читать невозможно на телефоне. Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы названия отображались полностью на одну строчку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разобрался. Атрибут tabMode = scrollabe

Comment: Я думаю, что вы можете это оформить как ответ, расписав подробности.

Answer (score 1):

Если проставить `tabMode` = `scrollabe`, то табы будут занимать нужное им пространство и скролиться, вместо ужимания до размеров экрана как у вас сейчас